# Можно ли объединить несколько ajax запросов в 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько ajax запросов. Все они обращаются к одной странице.
Эти запросы запускаются через setInterval через какое-то время. Можно ли их как-то объединить в 1, чтобы снизить нагрузку с бд.

Comment: Вы не с той стороны подходите к проблеме. Ее не на клиенте нужно решать, а на сервере. Вы же не напрямую с клиента обращаетесь к БД, а через скрипт на сервере, скорее всего. Вот он пусть и занимается объединением запросов к базе.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что получится - каждый ajax запрос будет самим собой, в объединенном или не объединенном состоянии - для базы разницы не будет - запросы будут отрабатываться по мере поступления, с отработкой всего положенного.

Что можно сделать - сделать промежуточный API/ кэш между базой и вашими запросами - например, с базы, с определенной периодичностью, скидывается вся страница/данные в файл, например, а уже каждый ajax - запросто тянет оттуда то, что ему нужно, не нагружая базу.

Таким образом, за одно обращение в базу Вы выгружаете все нужное для множества последующих ajax-запросов.

При этом, даже если секундный интервал,то все одно будет выгодно - одно обращение к базе будет.

Comment: ладно, буду разбираться. Спасибо